# Mysqli Prepared Statement not wokring

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a if statement that is used with a login page.

I have been trying to convert it to a mysqli prepared statement. It was previously just normal mysqli.

The problem is that no matter what id I enter it keeps saying Invalid Id! instead of the switching to the correct page.

```
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
require "connect.php";

session_start();

if (count($_POST) > 0)
    {
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT id, Login_ID, Name, User_Role_ID FROM user WHERE Login_ID = ?"));

    $lid = $_POST["id"];

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $lid);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id, $Login_ID, $Name, $User_Role_ID);

        $_SESSION["Student_DB_ID"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $Login_ID;
        $_SESSION["Name"] = $Name;
        $_SESSION["User_Role_ID"] = $User_Role_ID;

        switch ($User_Role_ID)
            {
        case "2":
            header("Location: ../views/student/");
            break; //Student
        case "1":
            header("Location: ../views/admin/");
            break; //Admin
        default:
                echo "Invalid ID!"; 
            } 

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

    }
}
```

Comment: because your stmt is not array. you should catch result set in a variable then check with if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for the mysqli_stmt_fetch() function (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). That function only returns booleans depending on whether the query completed successfully or not. You need to use bind_result() to return the values.

EDIT:

As per the comments below, this code should work, you had also removed the fetch() call which is still necessary:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    require "connect.php";

    session_start();

    if (count($_POST) > 0) {
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT id, Login_ID, Name, User_Role_ID FROM user WHERE Login_ID = ?")) {
            $lid = $_POST["id"];

            $stmt->bind_param("i", $lid);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $Login_ID, $Name, $User_Role_ID);
            $stmt->fetch();

            $_SESSION["Student_DB_ID"] = $id;
            $_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $Login_ID;
            $_SESSION["Name"] = $Name;
            $_SESSION["User_Role_ID"] = $User_Role_ID;

            switch ($User_Role_ID) {
                case "2":
                    header("Location: ../views/student/");
                    break; //Student
                case "1":
                    header("Location: ../views/admin/");
                    break; //Admin
                default:
                    echo "Invalid ID!"; 
            }

            /* close statement */
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, then $stmt wont be an array, it'll be an integer because you're returning an 'id' column from the database.

Comment: Iv updated my code. The if statement has been removed with the else being replaced by default. Yet it still only shows invalid id.

Comment: Edited the answer, should now work for you. You'd also removed the fetch() call which is still necessary.

Comment: Can I also just add that those session values will be easily editable by pretty much anyone with an ounce of web knowledge (depending on where you're storing the session). I'd recommend building a system like this just for educational purposes and not actually deploying this to a live website.

Comment: This is for educational purposes. How would you recommend storing the session values (currently just stored in the browser).

Comment: If you're storing anything in the session that could be manipulated, such as user ID, that would allow an attacker to access somebody else's account I would recommend having your session handler write all session data to a database instead of cookies. That way the only thing visible and open to tampering is the PHPSESSIONID value which is pretty much impossible to guess.

Comment: so would this article be a good tutorial - http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database

Comment: It's a bit outdated but yes, should work fine. However, don't use the mysql_ functions, use mysqli_ or even better PDO.

Comment: I have a small problem with the login code. In the form , when i submit it keeps taking me to /config/functions.php and the login code isnt working anymore.